# How can I place two textfields on the same row with Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using two textfields but I don't really know how I could place them on the same row. Right now they're placed on different rows.. My code:

```
   <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
           <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
      <v-text-field
        label="Name"
        solo
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
       <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
      <v-text-field
        label="Age"
        solo
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the v-cols with [`<v-row/>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#grid-system).

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">...</v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">...</v-col>
</v-row>
```

[image]

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-dawn-0qip2?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)

Comment: I guess I used the wrong word, what I meant was I want them on the same line.

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite understand what you mean by *"I want them on the same line"*. Can you provide an image of your expected result? Or much better, a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Basically I want the two text-fields to be next to each other, does that make sense?

Comment: I attached an output on my answer. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: You're welcome. Also, welcome to StackOverflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Goodluck with your project!